# What is the license for Microsoft XmlDiffPatch source code?

Tags: c#, xml, licensing, xmldiff

Microsoft distributes a software from 2002 called [XmlDiffPatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294). The pack also contains the source code for the application. Is there any license related to this source code? Can I change the code, recompile and reference it on my own application?

Comment: https://github.com/ca0v/XmlDiffPatch